# How to Read the 2nd and 3rd line then Every Fifth Line After: 2nd, 3rd, 7th, 8th, 12th, 13th, etc

Tags: python, line

I am trying to read certain lines from a text file in python.

My text file:

```
Data Set    
for this Event    
d1: p, t, h = 9, 12, 30    
d2: p, t, h = 12, 22, 11    
Data Set     
for this Event    
d1: p, t, h = 9, 12, 30    
d2: p, t, h = 12, 22, 11

etc.
```

How can I read the 2nd and 3rd line then the 7th 8th 12th 13th line so that I am only reading the lines with the data and skipping the lines that have Data Set for this Event.

Here is what I tried:

```
with open("d.txt") as f:

   for line2 in f.read().split("\n")[2::5]:
     print(line2)
   for line3 in f.read().split("\n")[3::5]:
     print(line3)
while line2:
   line = []
   line.append(line2)
   print(line)
```

But this only gives me the 2nd, 7th, 12th, 17th, etc lines. What am I doing wrong that I don't get the 2nd, 3rd, 7th, 8th, 12th, 13th, etc lines? If I write `line.append(line3)` instead I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "write.py", line 9, in <module>
    line.append(line3)
NameError: name 'line3' is not defined
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

EDIT: After looking at the answers and comments, I now try to write the following as my code:

```
from itertools import tee, islice
with open("d.txt") as f:
f1 = islice(f, 2, None, 5)
f2 = islice(f ,3, None, 5)

for l1, l2 in f1, f2:
    #print(f "{l1} --- {l2}")
    pass
```

However, I am now getting an error that I do not understand why it is coming about: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "write.py", line 6, in 
    for l1, l2 in f1, f2:
ValueError: too many values to unpack

I still don't really now how to fix this code. Any further guide would be highly appreciated!

Comment: That error message should be giving you a clue about a mismatch between what you "think" is happening and what is *actually* happening. Hint: Why would `line3` not be defined?

Comment: Haven't I defined it in the for loop above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the file object `f` is an `iterator` and is therefore exhausted once you go through it.

You can either use `f.seek(0)` to go back to the beginning as @user10987432 said, or you can use `itertools.tee()`

`itertools.tee()` allows you to make multiple independent iterators from a single iterator.

```py
from itertools import tee, islice
with open('foo') as f:
    f1, f2 = tee(f)
    for l1, l2 in zip(islice(f1, 2, None, 5), islice(f2, 3, None, 5)):
        print(f'{l1}  ---  {l2}')
```

will print

```
d1: p, t, h = 9, 12, 30
  ---  d2: p, t, h = 12, 22, 11

d1: p, t, h = 9, 12, 30
  ---  d2: p, t, h = 12, 22, 11
```

The `\n` is not stripped automatically (at least on my tests) so you will need to deal with it yourself

Comment: I understand now what my problem was... but why does the code have a syntax error:  File "write.py", line 6
    print(f '{l1}  ---  {l2}')
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Also, if I comment out the print to see where my error is I get the following error message: File "write.py", line 38

       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: I don't know about the syntax error. I did not run the code, but as fas as I can tell, there are no errors.

Comment: As for the indented block thing. If you comment out the print line, then you have no statements in the for block. You can add a pass statement (an empty statement that doesn't do anything) to deal with that

Comment: Using the pass statement, I find exactly where the error is:  File "write.py", line 4, in <module>
    for l1, l2 in zip(f1.read().split('\n')[2::5], f2.read().split('\n')[3::5]):
AttributeError: 'itertools.tee' object has no attribute 'read'. Don't understand why this is happening?

Comment: Oh that's because f1, f2 are no longer file objects. They are iterators and so do not have the read method. Use the islice function or something similar to get the slices out of f1 and f2

Comment: Isn't islice going to give the same problem. How can I do an iteration yet keep it a file object?

Comment: We don't need a file object anymore. We only need to iterate over the two iterators at a certain start point with a certain step which is exactly what islice does. If you need to write to the file or do other 'file only' things, then use the file object `f` but only after exhausting the two iterators or it can cause problems.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. But I still get errors when I try to do your suggestion as written in my edited question.

Comment: You need to use `zip()` to iterate over both `f1` and `f2` at the same time. I have tested and edited my answer. You can try this one now.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but there is a File "write.py", line 5
    print(f'{l1}  ---  {l2}')
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  error. I tried to rewrite the print function differently in case there are different ways to use print over the different python versions but that didn't work. The rest of the code does work because when I put a pass statement, it runs without an error. Yet, it refuses to print out the lines

Comment: What version of python are you using? the f-strings syntax is only available in 3.6 and above.

Comment: I have version 2.7.16.

Answer (score 0):

`f.read()` exhausts the the internal buffer of remaining characters to be read from the file. That means if you call `f.read()` twice in a row, the first call will work but the second will not (it will return an empty string since the file was exhausted by the first call). You will have to place the internal character cursor back to the beginning of the file using the `seek()` method. Alternatively, just read all the lines first and then do the rest.

```
with open("d.txt") as f:

    lines = f.readlines()

    for line2 in lines[2::5]:
        #...
    for line3 in lines[3::5]:
        #...
```

Another alternative is to use a regular expression to match and retain just those lines that follow the pattern you're looking for.

Comment: Changing f.read to f.readlines gives me this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "write.py", line 4, in <module>
    for line2 in lines("\n")[2::5]:
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: It's just `lines[2::5]`, not `lines("\n")[2::5]`. There is no need to try an split on newline characters anymore since you already have a list of lines.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out one reason that you're not getting the answer you expect is that you're consuming the generator after the first time you loop over it.

One way to get around this is that you can take advantage of the fact that the line numbers you want to read have on of only four values, modulo 10. E.g. 2, 3, 7, 8, 12, 13, 17, 18, ... and then use `enumerate` to only read the lines that you want.

```
valid = {2, 3, 7, 8}

with open("file.txt", "r") as fh:
    for n, line in enumerate(fh.readlines()):
        if n % 10 in valid:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

To select rows [2, 3, 7, 8, 12, 13, 17, 18...] you can check whether their index modulo 5 equals 2 or 3.

So, given row index i,

```
if (i % 5 == 2 or i % 5 == 3):
    # append row to list of relevant rows
```

Python indices start from 0 however, so what you actually need is row whose indices modulo 5 equal 1 or 2.

```
if (i % 5 == 1 or i % 5 ==2):
    # append row
```